# Google Colab: API error in opening up Python notebooks?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

[Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) provides no-devops Jupyter-notebook hosting, running on Google Drive but this works with most of my collegues but not on my account firing the API error such that

```
Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=...
The referrer https://...-apidata.googleusercontent.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
Error: The referrer https://...-apidata.googleusercontent.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
    at za.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_
    at Ba (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_
    at za.next_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_
    at Da.next (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_
    at b (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_
```

**How to resolve the Authentication API error occuring with Google Colab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the notebook load in an incognito window? A common cause of errors of this type is a conflict with one of your installed extensions.

Comment: Right, I disabled uMatrix -extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en) from `chrome://extensions/`.